# Counting : multiple queries or one query with multiple subqueries?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a summary script, for example, how many new users are there today, yesterday, this week, last week, this month, last month, so on.

I'm using CodeIgniter, so I wonder which one is better? Using multiple calls on models like this :

```
$this->model->get_today_users();
$this->model->get_yesterday_users();
$this->model->get_this_week_users();
// so on
```

Each one of the functions above only return the number of users with specific date range (e.g. SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE join_date=NOW() for today_users , etc - of course using CI active record ).

Or is it better having one single query with all necessary subqueries like this :

```
function stats(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE join_date=NOW()) as today');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE join_date=NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) as yesterday');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE WEEK(join_date)=WEEK(NOW()) ) as this_week');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE WEEK(join_date)=WEEK(NOW())-1 ) as last_week');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE MONTH(join_date)=MONTH(NOW()) ) as this_month');
$this->db->select('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE MONTH(join_date)=MONTH(NOW())-1 ) as last_month');
$this->db->from('users');
$ret = $this->db->get();
}
```

and then calling for example $data['stat'] = $this->model->stats(); so in views, I can call $stat->today, $stat->this_week, etc.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

UPDATE : What if I want to make a function that receives a date? Let's say I have to loop a month like this:

```
//for the sake of simplicity
foreach(day in a month as $r){
    $this->model->get_user_on_this_day($r);
}
```

This means for a 30-day month, it will loop 30 times! Is there any better way than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, neither of the approach is optimized.
Using least query is the best, so, you should do a GROUP BY query like below :

```
select date_format(join_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as the_date, count(*) as total
from users
where join_date between $start AND $end   <-- the date range
group by the_date;
```

Once you have the result, which you can set an array using date as key,
then you can further group by day, week, month...(whatever you want)

---

Seems like OP don't understand how this work :-

The above query is doing a one-time query, and will return the rows like

```
2011-12-09, 20 users join
2011-12-08, 10 users join
2011-12-07, 51 users join
...
```

All you have to do is to iterate the results (not active record)

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($start, $end));
$rtn   = array();
$total = 0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  $rtn[$row->the_date] = $row->total;
  $total += $row->total;
}
```

By the end of the loop, $total = total user registered from $start until $end.

Is more effective and optimize then doing 30 (or 31) queries during the loop of month-day.

Comment: That's also a possibility, but this means you have to first get all the data from the database and subsequently count inside you code. Doing the counting in the database and only then retrieve the results is probably faster if you have a large database. It all depends on the size of your database and what you want to do with the data, whether this approach is better than another.

Comment: You don't have to query all the rows, only those matching the $start, and $end (which you need that anyway)

Comment: AJ, that's true, but most it might still be an awful lot of rows that get returned by this query. As I said, that's not necessarily a bad thing, it just depends.

Comment: Single query is less expensive than multiple queries. And what do you mean by awful lots of rows? Is bounded to the $start, $end (which probably 60 day if for two months). You really consider that as a lots?

Comment: AJ, it depends how new many users the site gets each day. A site like SO would benefit from counting in the database. Many other sites as well. In this particular case? I don't know.

Comment: lol - no matter how, you still need to query database to get the results for that date range (daily, weekly, monthly ...) what is the diff?

Comment: your method looks nice, but if I do a subquery to count users per date, the query takes a whooping 10 seconds to load though the number of users is just 1000 or so. while if I do 1 query that loads all necessary subqueries, it takes less than a second.

Comment: This does not required any sub-query. You must understand this in different way. Update with your SQL

Comment: Sorry but this is not good advice. This is EXACTLY what database engines are designed for. Not only does it make your life easier it will do it better.

Comment: @savageguy  I don't blame you, please read all over again, is common senses using lesser query is less expensive. And the OP does not realize he is repeated himself by issuing multiple queries (which is just range selection)

Comment: what i meant is from your query, the result will be the distinct date of user's join date. It's useless, as the main point is to get the total register of each day. Now how can I achieve that? It's either looping the result query to count the total register per day or adding another subquery (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE join_date = the_date) as total_register or something like that. The where join_date is really optional because i want to know the all time statistic.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. *IF* you do look carefully my propose query, is a wrapping on the date. If you need a single date, then the $start and $end will be yesterday "00:00:00" to "23:59:59" (so you get a day of count). If you need a week count, then will be last week datet time ... BECAUSE the beauty of GROUP BY, it already return the daily-result count. Then do a sum on PHP will give you weekly total. Same thing apply to monthly ... You get the picture?

Comment: thanks! our query is pretty much the same, except i don't need to check the range and i never knew that using GROUP BY, we don't need to have another subquery to get the total record per row (this is the main point of it all I think). Using subquery, it takes 10-15 seconds per 1000 rows or so, using just count(*) takes less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer probably is: it depends. From a code reusability and readability perspective, the first option is probably better. On the other hand, the second option means you contact the database only one instead of three times. So the latter will probably be better performance-wise, as it means you only contact the database once, which means only one connection, one transaction etc. With large databases, slow connections etc. this would mean faster results.

Comment: yeah, i thought so too. But say in the future, I have to add stats per day/week/month, the second one will be tough to customize, don't you think?

Comment: Perhaps a little harder than the other option, yes. However, you should consider how often you will be making such a change and whether or not that outweighs the performance penalty you get when making the code slightly more maintainable.

Comment: Agree that though possibly not the best solution performance wise, the 1st option is definitely easier to read, maintain and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider creating a view over your user table, using the second option you mentioned ? There will be just one execution plan for your query and it will be processed only if data in main table are changed. And you will need only one simple query to get what you need.

And if you will need to add more counting, as you mentioned, you just add columns to the view.

Comment: but since it's just one single query, is there any difference to call it from a model or using MySQL view?

Comment: yes, i think so. the view is regenerated only if the main table changes. So there is much less countig. If you will ask db the same query over and over again, database will have to count rows over and over again, and it takes more database performance, than just select few fields from view.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, being able to use your first option with one query, would have an initizialization command.

`$this->model->buildmodel();`

You could make that save the records for week, month, yesterday ETC in an array which you can then call later, meaning it's easily customizable and is also faster, with one query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use separate queries and cache the result for a given date, so you never have to query it more than once.

Since people cannot join in the past, the data for a given query (other than the current day) will never change.